Is it haram to create a background check company?
Like the title says. I intend to create a background check company that would violate no ethical guidelines or do anything illegal, nor would it spy on anyone.
Simply put, the company would do an extensive search on the internet and create a report to provide companies with a person’s digital presence (for current employees they have or new employees they may hire). And we would also cater to individuals who may want to see their own digital presence or of others and possibly have it removed / buried.
For example, if someone has a social media account where they said bad comments but lost the login, we could help them remove that account and get it deleted so it does not pop up anymore in a search.
I want to make this clear: we are NOT spying on anyone, nor are we going to create accounts to spy on people. We are basically just doing advanced and algorithmic searches on the internet to uncover publicly available information.
I believe it is halal but I am worried about possibly exposing someone’s sins? Would that make it haram? But then again background checks seem fine to me?
Thank you to whoever answers this question, may Allah reward you. Amin.
